# A Rubber Band in a Rocket Ship

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

If I hang a mass onto a rubber band, the band gets stretched. The equation for this situation is  $ma\ =\ F_{r}-mg\ =\ 0$. Where $F_{r}\ =\ kx$. Where $x$ is the amount the rubber band stretches and the $k$ is the rubber band constant. Is my thought process correct so far? I then get into a rocket ship on Earth which starts accelerating upwards at $a_{2}$. For some reason, the rubber band now stretches more, what causes that? And how can one mathematically describe this situation?

Comment: You already wrote the equation ($ma=F_r-mg$), so it’s not clear what you’re looking for. Consider reviewing  [Equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle).

Comment: Re "For some reason...What causes that?" Inertia. Newton's Second Law. $F=mA$. In order for the hanging mass to keep up with the accelerating rocket, there must be a force acting between it and the rocket. That force is transmitted by the rubber band, which is stretched as a result: $F=-kx$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used Newton's second law, $ma = F_{r}-m\,g = k\,x-mg =m\, 0\Rightarrow x=\frac{mg}{k}$ when the acceleration of the mass was zero.

When the mass is acceleration with an acceleration $a_2$, the equation of motion is now $ma_2 = k\,x'-mg \Rightarrow x'=\frac{mg+ma_2}{k}$.

Thus the extension of the rubber band when the body is accelerating, $x'$, is greater than when the body is not accelerating, $x$.

Comment: Oh yes! I was getting my frame of reference and the ground's frame of reference mixed up.